# Trying to integrate Redux into React Navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm trying to integrate Redux, into an existing React Native application who use React Navigation.

The **dependencies** in **package.json** file are:

```
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.51.0",
"react-native-smart-splash-screen": "^2.3.5",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^1.0.0",
```

My code are:

**./App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { createStore } from "redux"
import SplashScreen from "react-native-smart-splash-screen"

import AppReducer from "./reducers/AppReducer"
import AppWithNavigationState from "./navigators/AppNavigator"


class App extends Component {

    store = createStore(AppReducer);

    componentWillMount() {
        SplashScreen.close({
            animationType: SplashScreen.animationType.scale,
            duration: 850,
            delay: 500,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppWithNavigationState />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App)

export default App
```

**./navigators/AppNavigator.js**

```
import { addNavigationHelpers, StackNavigator } from "react-navigation"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import StackLoading from "../screens/app/StackLoading"
import StackAuth from "../screens/auth/StackAuth"

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: StackAuth },
    Main: { screen: StackLoading },
},
{
    headerMode: 'screen',
    header: null,
    title: 'MyApp',
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
})

const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
    <AppNavigator
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: nav })}
    />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState)
```

**./reducers/AppReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import NavReducer from './NavReducer';

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
    nav: NavReducer,
});

export default AppReducer;
```

**./reducers/AppReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import { AppNavigator } from '../navigators/AppNavigator';

const router = AppNavigator.router;
const mainNavAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main')
const mainNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(mainNavAction);
const loginNavAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login')
const initialNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(loginNavAction, mainNavState)

function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
    let nextState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'Login':
            nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.back(),
                state
            );
            break;

        case 'Logout':
            nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }),
                state
            );
            break;

        default:
            nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
            break;
    }

    // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
    return nextState || state;
}

const initialAuthState = { isLoggedIn: false };

function auth(state = initialAuthState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'Login':
            return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true };
        case 'Logout':
            return { ...state, isLoggedIn: false };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  nav,
  auth,
});

export default AppReducer;
```

I have used various approaches following as many guides. The error that I continue to have is this:

> ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'state.routes[childIndex]')
>
> ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a
>   registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Please help me :\

Comment: Seems ok for me but please post code where you dispatch a navigation action

Comment: In the end I solved by following this guide: https://medium.com/async-la/a-stately-guide-to-react-navigation-with-redux-1f90c872f96e ;)

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

PrimaryNavigator is my top level navigator.

I am using some helper functions that disables pushing the same component multiple times to the stack which is a common problem in react-navigation.

My helper functions respectively ;

```
function hasProp(obj, prop) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
    }

    // Gets the current route name
    function getCurrentRouteName(nav) {
        if (!hasProp(nav, 'index') || !hasProp(nav, 'routes')) return nav.routeName;
        return getCurrentRouteName(nav.routes[nav.index]);
    }

    function getActionRouteName(action) {
        const hasNestedAction = Boolean(
            hasProp(action, 'action') && hasProp(action, 'type') && typeof action.action !== 'undefined',
        );

        const nestedActionWillNavigate = Boolean(hasNestedAction && action.action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE);

        if (hasNestedAction && nestedActionWillNavigate) {
            return getActionRouteName(action.action);
        }

        return action.routeName;
    }
```

And then setting the nav reducer :

```
const initialState = PrimaryNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'StartingScreen' })
    );

    const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        const { type } = action;

        if (type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE) {
            // Return current state if no routes have changed
            if (getActionRouteName(action) === getCurrentRouteName(state)) {
                return state;
            }
        }

        // Else return new navigation state or the current state
        return PrimaryNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state) || state;
    }
```

Finally, you can combine navReducer inside your combineReducers function.

Please let me know if my answer does not help your case

Answer (score 0):

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App) should happen in index.ios.js or index.android.js

your index.ios.js file should look like

```
import App from './src/App';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('your_app_name', () => App);
```